# Knockout Drop Downs Populated via ASP.NET MVC Server Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

So I am new to knockout and I was searching the web unable to find a straight answer.  Here is the situation.  I have a dropdown list in an asp.net mvc partial view.  It is populated via a viewmodel that has the values and an @Html helper, specifically dropdownlistfor.  The examples I see on the web appear to require a dependent observable array, but all the values for the drop down are set in the javascript (hardcoded)/instead of via server side code.  I simply want to make a span observe the output of a drop down list when the selected value changes (ie: for a live preview type functionality).  Any help would be much appreciated as I am sure I'm missing something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: So what is your actual question?  Are you having problems implementing the updating of the span tag?  Please include the code you've already tried and indicate where the question is.

Comment: The question is how to pull this off in general. I do not have any code yet as I was searching SO and the web for how to pull this off.  Basically, the scenario is if a drop down is populated with its values via server side code then how do I create the observable array indicated in this example http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html so I can update a span with the selected value?  A simple example would be a grade field.  If I have grades 7-12 and the user clicks on 8, I want a span's text to update to <span>8</span>.  I do not need to provide my drop down values in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<select data-bind="event: {change: mySelectChange},value:myValue">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<span data-bind="text:myText"></span>


<script>...

function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    this.myValue = ko.observable();
    this.myText = ko.observable();

    this.mySelectChange = function (obj, evt) {
        var item = $(evt.currentTarget);
        self.myText(item.find('option:selected').text());
    };
}

...
</script>
```

Comment: I think I may have found what I am looking for but I can't say I like it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1817193.aspx?Knockoutjs+with+Dropdown+list+on+asp+net+mvc3

Maybe it is better practice to use a JSON action method to get my values for the drop down and then follow the Knockout tutorial referenced above?  What is the best practice fellow ASP.NET MVC developers use as I would have expected this to be a common KO scenario?

Comment: Sorry I misread your initial question. You are looking for the selected text? I have done this using jQuery to get the text. I will edit my answer with an example

Comment: I am just curious I think this will work but doesn't it kind of go against the MVVM tenants Knockout is trying to establish?

Comment: Probably :) but it has worked well for me. 
You will definitely have an easier time adhering to MVVM if you start with JSON. In the long run is that actually better? There probably is a better way with custom binding handler but I have found that in the small number of scenarios like this one it's been easy/quick to use a jquery hack and move on.

Comment: Last comment, I had a discussion with a friend is it a fair statement to say Knockout is a replacement for Razor?  I think you probably should lean one way or the other given the types of issues in using KO to do these types of things in the context of a Razor page.  Hence this is probably where my disconnect is.

Comment: I don't know that I agree with that. Razor handles server-side data and knockout handles client-side. Once you have data from the server you may need interact. there is no reason why the two can't work hand in hand as they deal with different concerns. Now as for the issue at hand there may be a more MVVC appropriate way to handle it. 

Looks like I have some homework to do later. Good luck with your project. cheers

Comment: Accepted as the answer but I caution future readers that it is kind of a hack and you should probably work to re-engineer your view upon using Knockout to better fit the MVVM pattern.